# Return all rows with the same time stamp in an array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table pictured in the screenshot with several rows. The rows are inserted in bunches with the same time stamp. What I need to do is return all rows with the same time stamp in a php array so that I can output them to a table. I have no idea how to write such a query, please help. Thanks.[image: MYSQL table screenshot]

Comment: `SELECT * FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits WHERE submit_time = XXX LIMIT 50`?

Comment: This will only return rows for the defined time. What if I want for all the times, lets say an array of arrays, an array of all unique timestamps with arrays of fields in each timestamp.

Comment: Then you need to process it in your PHP script and improve your question because it's not evident what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible way of doing it. Using the `submit_time` as the key of the array to group them.

```
function get_results() {
    global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->get_results('select * from wp_cf7dbplugin_submits');

    $ret = [];

    foreach($result as $row) {

        if(!isset($ret[$row->submit_time])) {
            $ret[$row->submit_time] = array();
        }

        $ret[$row->submit_time][] = $row;
    }

    return $ret;
}
```